# as strong and fast as you might be, a wise ninja knows his greatest strength comes from the people who care for them

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I was wondering "as... as you might be" refers to "even though you think you are strong.

And if I change "as strong as you might be" to " to "as strong as you can be", I'm not sure if the meaning completely changes.

Furthermore, can I use it like this?

As rich as you might think, the most important thing in life is to keep you healthy.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: (1) Essentially, yes. // (2) 'Can' would be probably acceptable, but nowhere near as idiomatic as 'might' here. // (3) Ungrammatical. 'As rich as you might think you are, the most important thing in life is to keep yourself healthy.' is grammatical but not well formed. 'No matter how rich you might think you are, the most important thing in life is to keep yourself healthy.' handles the contrastive elements better. Note the need for the reflexive pronoun _yourself_ here.

Comment: In this context, "as strong as you might be" means "as strong as you are". It doesn't make sense to say "as rich as you might think", it should be "as rich as you might think you are" (or I think "as rich as you may be" (no "think") is better).

Comment: You can also read it as meaning "Although you are strong and fast your greatest srength comes from your family". I've changed it a bit becasue there is a mismatch of pronouns referring to the same person in the title quote. Firstly there is a second person pronoun (...as you might be..) then there is a third person singular pronoun (...his greatest strength...) and finally there is a third person plural pronoun  (...the people who care for them...). Whatever pronoun is used at the start it should be used subsequently when referring to the same person. If you start with the wrong one change it.